# How to locate the source of an outward wind-draft, that's going outwards from my room's window?

Tags: windows, draft, wind

I have hung up a wet cloth over my window's curtain rod. The idea is that it's going to naturally cool the incoming wind. I ran into some issues during this setup, but after some effort I solved it all, thanks to DIY stackexchange!

After that I've been constantly seeing the wind going outwards from my room. The curtains, and my wet cloth just stick to the window because there's a slight breeze going outwards.

I cannot pin-point the location for it. I've closed every window, every door throughout my house to try and block it. And yet I see the wind somehow going outwards from my room.

**How can I locate where this wind-draft is originating from?**

**Additional info:**

Locating this has been one hell of a frustrating experience. I tried with the  "hold a strip of paper up" technique and it moves around in all directions. The only time it's consistent is near the window where we know that the wind is going outwards.

Comment: It's more likely that the house is naturally positive pressure which would force air out of the gaps in the window. This positive pressure can be due to a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [smoke pencil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00746F5HG)

This is what pro hvac guys  use to find drafts. it produces a thin stream of smoke that you can direct at the perimeter of the window. When you observe the smoke being drawn into a gap you will have isolated a leak.

[image]

Comment: Some dry ice and warm water is a way to make a nontoxic smoke at home. Many grocery stores carry dry ice in my area. It's also fun to put in a tub close to the front porch on Halloween, my kids loved the effect of the fog.

Comment: @EdBeal I've never bought dry ice. Wouldn't that be expensive? I think I'm just going to go with a blown out matchstick for now since I don't have all these equipment.

Comment: Not expensive in my area, years ago shipping companies had so much excess it was almost free. Today you pay by the pound.. It's just co2 that is released as a liquid that turns into the solid we know as dry ice. I have a "box" to make it and have seen cheap "bags" to make it but they are not as dense. What is co2 it is the bubbles in your soft drinks and beer and what we exhale by ~ 5% of what we exhale with every breath. I also used this method with our high purity water in a class 10 clean room, just gas that is natural, passed class 1 tests and saved thousands.